# Rock, paper, scissors simple game in java

Tags: java

Hi I am making a simple rock, paper, scissors game and was having some trouble getting my compare method to get executed. The game prompts the user for input, and then using the computersTurn method to allow the computer to randomly select rock paper or scissors. When I try and pass both these values into my compare method, it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be awesome!

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class sillyGame {

public static void compare (String choice1, String choice2)

{

    if (choice1.equals(choice2))

    {

    System.out.println("The result is a tie!");   

    }



    if (choice1.contains("rock"))

    {
        if (choice2.contains("scissors"))
        {
            System.out.println("rock wins");
        }

        if (choice2.contains("paper"))
        {
            System.out.println("paper wins");
        }
    }   



        if (choice1.contains("scissors"))
    {
        if (choice2.contains("rock"))
        {
            System.out.println("rock wins");
        }

        if (choice2.contains("paper"))
        {
            System.out.println("scissors wins");
        }

    }



    if (choice1.contains("paper"))

    {
        if (choice2.contains("rock"))
        {
            System.out.println("paper wins");
        }

        if (choice2.contains("scissors"))
        {
            System.out.println("scissors wins");
        }

    }




}

public static String computersTurn(String compFinalChoice, double randomNum){

randomNum = Math.random();


    if (randomNum < 0.34) 
    {
        compFinalChoice = "rock";

    } 

    else if(randomNum <= 0.67) 
    {
        compFinalChoice = "paper";

    } 

    else 
    {
        compFinalChoice = "scissors";

    }

       System.out.println("The computer chooses " + compFinalChoice);
      return compFinalChoice;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    String userChoice = scan.nextLine();
    String computerDec = " ";
    double rand = 0.0;
    computersTurn(computerDec, rand);
    compare(userChoice, computerDec); 
}
```

Comment: What is the output your getting ? and in the IF statements , you might want to generalize it , like if (choice1.contains(choice2)) , also try  put and else statement in the end for the sake of debugging

Comment: You can accept the answer that worked best for you by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Please do some reading and make sure you understand what is pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `computersTurn` method doesn't need any parameters. You're just passing it `" "` and `0.0`.

Try changing it to this method:

```
public static String computersTurn() {

    // declare them here
    double randomNum = Math.random();
    String compFinalChoice = "";

    if (randomNum < 0.34) {
        compFinalChoice = "rock";
    }
    else if(randomNum <= 0.67) {
        compFinalChoice = "paper";
    } 
    else {
        compFinalChoice = "scissors";
    }

    System.out.println("The computer chooses " + compFinalChoice);
    return compFinalChoice;
}
```

And then in your `main` method, make sure when you call the `computersTurn()` method, you *assign* it to a String. Calling it does nothing for you; you need to keep the return value:

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    String userChoice = scan.nextLine();
    String computerDec = computersTurn(); // assign it here
    compare(userChoice, computerDec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is a good rule of thumb when trying to figure out if you should have parameters in your method or not?

Comment: @HaagenDaaS when you need them for something (and they already have a value that you need). If you calculated the random number in your `main` method and needed to pass it to your `computersTurn` method, you should make that a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a String (or a double) from a caller so I think you should re-factor `computersTurn` like so

```
public static String computersTurn() {
  String choice = "scissors";
  double randomNum = Math.random();
  if (randomNum < 0.34) {
    choice = "rock";
  } else if (randomNum <= 0.67) {
    choice = "paper";
  }
  System.out.println("The computer chooses "
      + choice);
  return choice;
}
```

Then you can do something like this in `main`

```
String computerDec = computersTurn();
```

or

```
String userChoice = scan.nextLine();
compare(userChoice, computersTurn());
```